# Django - display multiple views in one template

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-tables2, django-simple-history

I am currently working on a Django project, in which I want to build a kind of dashboard, which may have actually two bootstrap columns (in the future maybe 3-4). In each column, content from a database is to be displayed. Currently, this means that I want to show two tables. One which shows all entries for a model and a table which shows the last history entries (django-simple-history). The tables are rendered using django-table2.

First of all I tried to solve the problem with the MultiTableMixin. Unfortunately without success. My current idea is to logically split the content into two views and then add a view for each column. I tried to have the views displayed inside iframes. Also, this not working as good as thought.

What are the options for my problem. Or am I thinking too complicated and getting lost?

Comment: you could use `inclusion_tag`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your headline is a bit misleading since your issue is actually quiet simple:

 Just make two queries within your view to get two query objects with which you render the columns/tables. So you have one view (function) but the logic is still seperated content wise:

```
def get_data_for_columns(request):
    column_all_data = YourModel.objects.all()
    column_latest_data = YourModel.objects.all().order_by('-publish_date')[10:] # 10 latest objects by publish date

    context = {
        'all_data': column_all_data
        'latest_data': column_latest_data
    }
    
    return render(request, 'your_template.html', context)
```

template:

```
# example loop data and render table

   <table>
     <tr>
       {% for item in all_data %}

       <td>{{ item.value }}</td>

       {% endfor %}
     </tr>
   </table>

   <table>
     <tr>
       {% for item in latest_data %}

       <td>{{ item.value }}</td>

       {% endfor %}
     </tr>
   </table>
```

Comment: Okay, this works fine if I only have to display data from a database. So at the Moment my problem should be solved. But what is if I want to add a third column with a class based view like a generic CreateView?

Comment: @LukasW. Then you can i.e nest your functions in a single view. Happy it helps! Would appreciate if you could upvote and accept the answer then.

Comment: I accept and upvote your answer. But can show a example how to nest functions with different logic in a single view?

Comment: Don't you think that your solution would lead to have a messy big view (function) at the end? The reason I'm asking this, is that I've faced a view with more than 300 lines of code with a single template file (which is massive either) and I think something is not right here! and I must refactor this view. Cause if it was separated from frontend using APIs, there would be some little APIs for such a page, and even the page itself would be built with some little components, and its code was much more clear to read and understand (both sides).